# How can we pass a empty Value to dateTime Parameter to a stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to pass an empty Value in the `dateTime` Parameter to a stored procedure
`EndDate=null`:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = EndDate
```

Comment: Have you tried NULL?

Comment: s, but it showing datetime cannot convert to null

Comment: Hai Swetha, Could you please include the procedure definition and the code that you are using to call the sp?

Comment: please post some code here so we can analyze the problem

Comment: so y u doing downVote? for my questions

Comment: Try  `DBNull.Value` as your value to sqlparameter

Comment: look this image while i put this it showingthis errorhttp://i.stack.imgur.com/yuJh5.png

Comment: @swethavijayan : use AddWithvalue, See the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As like the error message says it is not possible to convert the null or DbNull.Value to DateTime if you specify the expected datatype as `SqlDbType.DateTime` in add method. So better option is AddWithValue. Use like the following:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateparameter", DBNull.Value);
```

For more [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1132283.aspx?Send%20null%20values%20to%20a%20stored%20procedure%20in%20c%20)

Comment: thanks it works for me... also the link help me to learn more

Comment: happy to help you swetha

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value 
= StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: i don't need to convert the datetime to string . i need to handle the nullvalue